# Are shopping questions on topic for the site?

Tags: discussion, scope

On other Stack sites it is quite common for purchasing assistance and shopping ideas to be off topic. The reason being these types of questions become outdated very quickly as technology changes, a store goes out of business, or a product is no longer available.

When looking at this: [Makerbot Smart extruder+ heat block and nozzle question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/7226/11242) - there is the basis for asking about Mk10/Mk11 printer heads, but they also ask about where to purchase them.

**Are these types of questions on-topic for 3D Printing?**

Answer (score 2):

Asking for which type of extruder is used by this assembly is on-topic, where to buy (shopping) is off-topic. This is discussed in [this question](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276/game-plan-what-is-on-topic/295#295).

[Another question](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/on-topic-purchasing-acquisition-question-types) that points out the differences between "shopping questions" is still unanswered but discusses differences between shopping questions. Some can still be answered based on how they are formulated.

Generally, "where to buy stuff" should be left to the OP, he can Google that himself, but what it is called/named or how does it look like or if there are printable or alternate version available are IMHO on-topic.

Comment: I totally agree 100%, but I often, cheekily, provide a link or two as suggestions, just so that they know what they should be looking for. For example, the [thermistor question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/ultimaker-original-temperature-sensor-replacement/6851#6851).

Comment: @Greenonline Maybe we should ask those to join in [chat] and pass that information there. Adding an image to show what they look for or describe what they look for might be an idea, but my general opinion is to not answer those questions with direct links. In the past I referred to "Those typical auction sites or Chinese vendor sites", or something in that line. I guess most people will understand where to get it then...

Comment: Yeah, good points. I think that adding an image is harmless, but if new people see links in my answers, I guess then they might feel encouraged to ask a question hoping that someone will answer and provide a sneaky link - point taken, I hadn't given it much thought, tbh. I suppose that it never pays to be *overly* helpful. :-)